# Rails Association if boolean is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, associations, conditional-statements

I have two models, an user model and a course model

The user schema looks like this:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username",                        default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "first_name",                      default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "last_name",                       default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "password_digest",                 default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "email",                           default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "email_unconfirmed",               default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "email_verification_token",        default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "password_reset_token",            default: "",    null: false
    t.datetime "password_reset_token_expires_at"
    t.boolean  "admin",                           default: false
    t.boolean  "teacher",                         default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

The course schema looks like this:

```
create_table "courses", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

And the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taught_courses, :foreign_key => :teacher_id 
end
```

I only want to have users where the teacher/admin boolean is `true` to have `taught_courses`
but as far as I know you can't wrap the association in an if statement, cause the teacher?/admin? method is not available so how do I handle this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that the way you want but you can just not allow them to create courses if they're not an admin/teacher

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taught_courses, -> { where(admin: true, teacher: true)}, :foreign_key => :teacher_id 
end
```

You can read up more about [ActiveRecord Conditional Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) online, and see an example here:

```
4.1.3.1 where

The where method lets you specify the conditions that the associated object must meet.

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, -> { where active: true }
end
```

---

**Update**

If you're going to use another model for verification, you may want to use `.joins`. However, considering you're pinging the original model, you may wish to use [`ActiveRecord Association Extensions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)

These give you access to the `proxy_association` objects, which give you the ability to access the "parent" data through memory:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taught_courses, :foreign_key => :teacher_id do
        def admins_and_teachers
            user = proxy_association.owner
            where("users.admin = ? AND users.teacher = ?", user.admin, user.teacher)
        end
    end
end
```

I think this will work; if not, it will definitely be the path I'd look at

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that. The problem is that these `where` conditions use the course table and not the user table.

Comment: Thanks for feedback - let me revise my answer